# Applications, Generalisations and developments of Green-Tao Theorem after 2018

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, graph-theory, analytic-number-theory, ergodic-theory

The well-known Green-Tao Theorem is definitely one of the most striking results among different area of Mathematics such as: Number Theory, Combinatorics, Graph Theory, Ergodic Theory,... etc.

https://annals.math.princeton.edu/2008/167-2/p03

Hence, I would like to enquire about where the applications, generalisations and developments of Green-Tao Theorem can be found (especially, the ones have been achieved after 2018).

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please give a (good) reference for the initial theorem.

Comment: Having a look at the abstracts of papers that cite Green-Tao would be a good start.